# Creating a Serial Queue in Swift 3

Tags: swift, multithreading

I am familiar on how to create a serial queue in Swift 2, but things have changed, and now I'm not sure how to do it. I tried just creating a new DispatchQueue, but I'm not sure what all the parameters mean. Somebody please help. Thank you.

Comment: `let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "...")` or if you want to set the queue priority, `let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "...", qos: .utility)`. Bottom line, as long as you  don't set the `attributes` to `.concurrent`, it will be a serial queue.

Comment: let newQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "newname")
 newQueue.sync { 

 // your code

 }